# Kettle - Filter duplicated rows by field value

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a single input stream from a csv file. This stream is from a User Table, where the user may be duplicated with different ID's.

I need to clean this stream. The combo of [Name + Surname] always is unique, but I need to make a comparison before selecting one, because I want to keep the information of the most recent and create a new field based on the comparison of other value.

I have a Timestamp that will be used for selecting the row.

This is a example of input stream:
[image]

And this is a example of the output I want:
[image]
What tool would be the best for this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with a bit of sorting and grouping in pentaho kettle.

1. CSV-File Input with your table (be sure that TimeUpdated is a date-format)
2. Sort-Step: Sort by Name, Surname, Surname2, TimeUpdated (Asc: No)
3. Group by-Step: Group by Name, Surname, Surname2; Aggregate: id (first value), TimeUpdated (first value), Status (Concatenate String seperated by (value: +)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. Sort the rows by Name, Surename1, Surename2 and TimeUpdate using a step called **Sort rows**;
2. Do either of the following:

   - A step called **Unique rows**, where the *Fields to compare on* would state the fields which you are willing to make unique;
   - A step called **Group by**, where *The fields that make up the group* would state those fields you want to make unique, and the *Aggregates* would state all other fields. The **Type** dropdown next to each of the aggregates should be set according to the way you sorted your data in step 1:

     - If you decided that the most important rows to keep, out of duplicates, are the ones with the most recent data, and you sorted TimeUpdate descending , then choose *Type* = "Last value" or "Last non--null value" for all of the Aggregates;

Another thing you should note, but that's more general - there's a step called **Memory Group by**, which saves you the expensive computational time of sorting before grouping, but that step is good only if you can make sure that the data passing through it won't overflow the memory, i.e. small data sets.